# Xamarin.Forms Localization returns always default language

Tags: xamarin, localization, xamarin.forms, internationalization

I am trying to implement I18N / Localization for Xamarin.Forms as described here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/ - however even though I set the language on my device to french and have a Resx File for french, there's always the default translation returned. I already tried deactivating fast deployment (as recommended on the forementioned website), but no success so far.

In this line:

```
var translation = ResMgr.Value.GetString(Text, ci);
```

the value ci is fr-CH, the returned string however is the default language and not French

```
// You exclude the 'Extension' suffix when using in Xaml markup
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    readonly CultureInfo ci;
    const string ResourceId = "ResxI18N.Resx.Resources";

    private static readonly Lazy<ResourceManager> ResMgr = new Lazy<ResourceManager>(() => new ResourceManager(ResourceId
                                                                                                              , typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));

    public TranslateExtension()
    {
        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS || Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
        {
            ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
        }
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return "";

        var translation = ResMgr.Value.GetString(Text, ci);

        if (translation == null)
        {

        }
        return translation;
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:ResxI18N.Helpers;assembly=ResxI18N"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResxI18N" x:Class="ResxI18N.ResxI18NPage">
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate Welcome}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

The full example can be found here: https://github.com/hot33331/ResxI18N

Comment: I think  you could share  a demo ,which can reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource should be set with **Embedded**.

Change the option in this following image.

[image]